# How to use the RegisterXLL method in a C# VSTO for Excel

Tags: excel, vsto, add-in, excel-dna, xll

I have created a xll addin using ExcelDNA so that it can be easily written in C#.

I also have a VSTO and I want the VSTO to Register the xll file, so that I can use the custom functions when the user is using the VSTO plugin for excel.

This is what is written in the Addin startup method:

```
Application.RegisterXLL(@"SMPXLL.xll");
```

It would work if I wrote the absolute address of the .xll file. However, I want it to be a relative address. I just don't know what the file is relative to.

Comment: See the accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3196505/cant-load-xll-programmatically)

Comment: @Hewitt, I m not sure that it works with a xll created by ExcelDNA because I think that in this case the xll is not pure C code. I have added the excel-dna tag (in review), maybe that Govert (author of excel-dna) will have a chance to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Application.RegisterXLL(...)` works fine for Excel-DNA add-ins.

You can find the path of the executing assembly (the VSTO library) using code like this: [How do I get the path of the assembly the code is in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52797/how-do-i-get-the-path-of-the-assembly-the-code-is-in)

Then build the full path to the .xll file relative to that path.

Comment: I've actually moved the .xll file to the same folder that the VSTO project's .dll is in.

So does that just mean that I can just write the following?

    Application.RegisterXLL("SMPXLL.xll");

Comment: Nevermind, I have solved the problem. I'm a beginner so it took me a while to really understand what was going on. Thank you so much for your help.